# CSS: 100vw not expanding entire width of parent div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a simple html / css column chart that has a horizontal plot line `.chart-line`, however, I can't seem to get the plot line to expand the entire width of the parent div.

I need to make sure that when it expands the entire width of the div, I can still control where it's placed by the inline `style="bottom: 50%"` where the % will place it exactly at x% of the columns.

Below is my current code, the red line is the plot line that I can't get to expand entire width of the scrollable parent div.

```css
.chart-container {
    overflow-x: auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.chart {
    height: 200px;
    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap: 5px;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(100, 1fr);
    position: relative;
}
.chart-line {
    min-width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    right: -100%;
    left: 0;
}
.chart .bar {
    grid-row: 1/101;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    width: 60px;
}
.chart .bar.bar-50 {
    grid-row-start: 51;
}
.chart .bar.bar-100 {
    grid-row-start: 1;
}
.chart .bar {
    background-color: #0074d9;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart-container">
        <div class="chart">
            <div class="chart-line" style="bottom: 50%"></div> <!-- horizonal plot line -->
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `100vw` is as long as the actual viewport, so if the element extends past the viewport, the line will not reach the end of the element. Try `min-width: 100%`

Comment: @zer00ne Thanks for the suggestion! I edited the question with the updated code, however the `.chart-line` is still not extending 100% for some reason.

Comment: changing the right position from `0` to `-100%` gets more of what you want.  Not sure why it's not spanning the entire width of the parent though.

Comment: @ScottZ Thanks for the suggestions as well! This is so odd though, that also doesn't seem to make it span the full width of the parent still. 

Edit.. actually it looks like it does, however it pushes the length of the parent div well beyond the chart columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the width of the `.chart` was auto which means it was limited to the `.chart-container` width which means your bars were overflowing past the parent and the `.chart-line` was not overflowing because of the position absolute.

add `width:max-content;` to `.chart` to make it large enough for the `.bar` children:

```css
.chart-container {
    overflow-x: auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.chart {
    height: 200px;
    width:max-content;
    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap: 5px;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(100, 1fr);
    position: relative;
}
.chart-line {
    min-width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.chart .bar {
    grid-row: 1/101;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    width: 60px;
}
.chart .bar.bar-50 {
    grid-row-start: 51;
}
.chart .bar.bar-100 {
    grid-row-start: 1;
}
.chart .bar {
    background-color: #0074d9;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart-container">
        <div class="chart">
            <div class="chart-line" style="bottom: 50%"></div> <!-- horizonal plot line -->
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
            <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That worked! Also just found that changing `display: grid` to `display: inline-grid` works as well! Thank you!

Comment: no problem, just make sure to understand why this was happening here's a tip: use 
background-color on parent divs to see what's happening when a behavior like this occurs and don't forget to inspect with browser dev tools.